# Is objc_setAssociatedObject not available in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, objective-c-category

I'm trying to add "properties" to categories using associate objects API.

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &kIsAnimatingAssocObjKey, animating, 
OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
```

Xcode complains:

> Implicit declaration of function 'objc_setAssociatedObject' is invalid in C99

and

> Use of undeclared identifier 'OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC'

Xcode 4.5.2, iOS SDK 6 with deployment target 6. It does not work.

None of the [articles](http://www.techpaa.com/2012/04/adding-properties-to-categories-and.html) on obj_assoc mention that I must import anything special.

Answer (score 63):

Simply import the runtime header:

`#import <objc/runtime.h>`

Comment: You answer was entered 4 seconds earlier, therefore I will delete mine  (-:

Comment: Thanks!  Any idea how we are supposed to learn that?  Apple documentation used to say.  Now it just says "Objective-C framework"